# Regresar al activity anterior

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo la siguiente aplicación en la cual al iniciar muestra una lista de contactos y al presionar sobre uno muestra su nombre, numero de teléfono y correo, ahora cuando yo entro a ese segundo activity y presiono el botón back mi aplicación se cierra por completo, y lo que yo quiero es que al presionar el botón esta me regrese a mi activity principal.

Este es un fragmento de codigo de mi MainActivity donde se encuentra mi primera actividad:

```
lstcontactos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            Intent iniciar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detalle.class);
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vnombre),contactos.get(i).getNombre());
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vtelefono),contactos.get(i).getTelefono());
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vemail),contactos.get(i).getEmail());
            startActivity(iniciar);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Y este codigo corresponde a mi segundo activity:

```
public class Detalle extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvnombre;
TextView tvtelefono;
TextView tvemail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);

    Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nombre = datos.getString("Nombre");
    String telefono = datos.getString("Telefono");
    String email = datos.getString("Email");

    tvnombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvnombre);
    tvtelefono = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtelefono);
    tvemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvemail);

    tvnombre.setText(nombre);
    tvtelefono.setText(telefono);
    tvemail.setText(email);
}

public void llamar(View v) {
    String telefono = tvtelefono.getText().toString();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +telefono)));
}

public void enviarCorreo(View v) {
    String email = tvemail.getText().toString();
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent((Intent.ACTION_SEND));
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
}
}
```

[image: Esta es mi activity principal]

[image: Y esta mi segunda activity]

Comment: Hola, prueba a quitar el finish(); en el intent del primer activity que te lleva al segundo activity.

Comment: Agrega por favor el error que se muestra en el LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si al mostrar la Activity `Detalle` desde `MainActivity` estas usando `finish()`, nunca podrás regresar a `MainActivity` puesto que estas destruyendo esta Activity, te sugiero no usar `finish()` al lanzar la Activity que muestra los detalles del contacto :

```
lstcontactos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
            Intent iniciar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Detalle.class);
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vnombre),contactos.get(i).getNombre());
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vtelefono),contactos.get(i).getTelefono());
            iniciar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.vemail),contactos.get(i).getEmail());
            startActivity(iniciar);
            //* finish();
        }
    });
```